# Python Pandas DataFrame: Replace values in each row for each column based on conditions

Tags: python, panel-data

I have the following dataset (check the link below):

[The stock returns from 2006 to 2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE2hd.png)

I need to assign values for each company's stock return in each year in 4 quantiles (check the link below).

[Distributed stock returns from 2006 to 2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge90k.png)

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=['Excess Returns'], index_col='Data')
df = pd.concat(df[frame] for frame in df.keys())
df = df.replace('-', '')
df = (df).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Could you help to write the cycle for sorting?

The following code does not work:

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df.iloc[i] <= df.quantile(0.2, axis = 1).iloc[i]:
        df.iloc[i] = 1
    elif df.iloc[i] > (df.quantile(0.2, axis = 1) and df.iloc[i] <= df.quantile(0.4, axis = 1)).iloc[i]:
        df.iloc[i] = 2
    elif df.iloc[i] > (df.quantile(0.4, axis = 1) and df.iloc[i] <= df.quantile(0.6, axis = 1)).iloc[i]:
        df.iloc[i] = 3
    elif df.iloc[i] > (df.quantile(0.6, axis = 1) and df.iloc[i] <= df.quantile(0.8, axis = 1)).iloc[i]:
        df.iloc[i] = 4
    else:
        df.iloc[i] = 5

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please provide your sample input and output in the text of the question, not as an image or link, to make a [mcve] that we can use to test

Comment: Please avoid links or images in the question. That will make it easier for us to test the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this -

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
quantiles_0.75 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df<=df.quantile([0.75]).loc[0.75], 1, 2), columns=df.columns])
```

Please note that the above will create a dataframe `quantiles_0.75` with same columns as `df` but with values according to the rule which you specified.

In case of more conditions, I think a modified version of @David's post will also be useful in case you want the result into a dataframe -

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df <= df.quantile(0.2), 1, np.where((df > df.quantile(0.2)) & \
                                                 (df <= df.quantile(0.4)), 2, \
                                                 np.where((df > df.quantile(0.4)) & \
                                                 (df <= df.quantile(0.6)), 3, 4)), columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Your solution is convenient if we have only 2 sorting groups. Could you please share your ideas on how to solve this problem for 5 sorting groups if any?

Comment: Please check if it works. It is just an extension of what @David suggested - the result of np.where being fed into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

My idea based on previous contributors. I feel it is quite optimal solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df <= df.quantile(0.2), 1, np.where((df > df.quantile(0.2)) & \
                                                     (df <= df.quantile(0.4)), 2, \
                                                     np.where((df > df.quantile(0.4)) & \
                                                     (df <= df.quantile(0.6)), 3, 4)), columns=df.columns)
```